# Search issue when saving a file into a subfolder

Tags: nautilus, search

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 with Nautilus and tracker installed. I have no issue when searching files with super key or within explorer.

However, when I want to save a file in a specific location, I want to search the location, it shows nothing. It works for some specific folders so I think I need to index folders but I don't know how to do it. I think the issue could be for sub folders but I am not sure.

Moreover, the issue is only when I save a file. I don't have any problem searching a file elsewhere.

Can someone help me solve this issue?

Many thanks

Comment: You probably refer to searching in a File Open or File Save dialog opened from within an application? Please edit your post to clarify.